# How do you show that thermal broadening at Fermi distribution is~3.5kT when the temperature is nonzero and finite?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

I searched and found out that the thermal broadening is given as $3bkT/(4a^2)$, but this way need some data to find out $a$ and $b$, as the $a$ and $b$ is just a number given by a model.
I can't find a clue to find the thermal broadening just with Fermi distribution function and without any experimental data.
I am working on this problem by trying to integrate the Fermi distribution function, as it seems to be the only thing I can do with this function, but that's all I could do.

Answer (score 0):

Hint;

Try finding two energy values at which the value of the derivative of the Fermi distribution function is half the maximum value (find the full width at half maximum of the derivative of the Fermi function $f'(E)$). You have $$f(E)=\frac{1}{e^{\frac{E-E_{F}}{kT}}+1}$$then find $f'(E)$ and its maximum value. For your reference, the maximum of $f'(E)$ is $-\frac{1}{4kT}$, where $k$ is Boltzmann's constant.